# Laravel migration undefined index

Tags: laravel, migration

I am using Laravel 5.3.I deleted one of my migration files name 'feature' and everything related to it very carefully like its id from other tables etc.then i manually deleted the table from database.But now while i'm running the command "php artisan migrate:refresh".It's showing error exception with 'undefined index:***_create_features_table'.And when I'm running just 'php artisan migrate'.it shows that it was successful and all the tables successfully appear in the database.but then when i run migrate:refresh all the table disappears.what should i do to completely delete the migration file?

Comment: have you tried to truncate migration table?

Comment: no.can you please mention how i suppose to do that?

Comment: In your database you have a table name `migrations`. There all migrate information saved. first delete all records. After that run `php artisan migrate`. This may help you

Comment: tried your solution..now its even not taking the migrate command

Comment: If the problem persist. please follow the below procedure.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this.

First Manually delete the migration file under `app/database/migrations/my_migration_file_name.php`

Reset the composer autoload files: `composer dump-autoload`

Modify your database: Remove the last entry from the `migrations table`

Comment: thank you Manish for consulting.I think this procedure will work.next time I'l go through this.

Comment: Thanks for this bro

Comment: used sequel pro to delete the rows from migrations table and this worked like a charm. thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I did.I cleared all the data from the database including all tables and then ran 'php artisan migrate'..that is how i made it work..But i am looking for a better solution which will not need to delete everything from the database.

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` will rectified all your issues. So don't panic. If you are worry then backup your project first. before running the above script.

Comment: Clearing the database tables worked for me. dumping the autoload in Composer didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try check that you have the correct migrations first

`php artisan migrate:status`

Then you can try something like

`php artisan migrate:refresh --step=1`

And check again the status.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Undefined index` error and your migration was made with --path option, then add to your `ModuleServiceProvier` `boot()` method:

```
$this->loadMigrationsFrom(base_path('database/migrations/directory-name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

in the migration just add $table->index(['column Name 1',''column Name 1']);

Answer (score -1):

With my case, I forgot to do the Laravel migrate before running Infyomlabs to create scaffold!
So one of the reasons for "Undefined index" is that the table is not there yet.