# migrate:refresh is not working after deleting a migration

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have created a migration table '`result`' and deleted it but now migration refresh is not working. Showing following error.

> [ErrorException]  Undefined index:
>   2017_02_20_090135_create_results_table

I have used composer dump-autoload and it doesn't solve the problem.

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel migration undefined index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616952/laravel-migration-undefined-index)

Comment: Muhammad Saqlain it doesn't help.

Comment: Did the below answer solve your issue or do you need more help with it? If it does solve your problem please would mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to your `migrations` table in your database and delete the row where migration = 2017_02_20_090135_create_results_table.

One way to do this would be:

```
php artisan tinker
```

then

```
DB::table('migrations')->where('migration', '2017_02_20_090135_create_results_table')->delete();
```

It might also be an idea to delete the table as well.

Hope this helps!